# I want to calculate sum from different table

Tags: php, mysql

[image: This data comes from different tables]I want to calculate sum from different table. I'm New in PHP Please help me.
Below i have attached screenshot, All the values comes from database.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="sum_table">
    <tr>
    <th style="background-color: #ff7f7f">Items:</th>
    <td style="background-color: #44768e">Amount</td>
    </tr>
        <th>Total</th>
<td><?php

$qry = mysqli_query ("
SELECT sum(Price) 
  FROM rice 
 WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
");
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
echo $row2['total'];


$qry = mysqli_query ("
SELECT sum(Price) 
  FROM egg 
 WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() 
,'%Y-%m-01')
");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
echo $row['total'];

$total = $row['total'] + $row2['total'];
echo $total;

?></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: u missed alias `sum(Price) as total` in your queries

Comment: echoing the comment from devpro, the php code is anticipating a column named `total` in the resultset, but the SQL query is not returning a column with that name. As devpro suggests, assign an alias `AS total` to the expression in the SELECT list. of both queries.

Comment: After adding alias same result display total zero

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - but note that this kind of thing is highly symptomatic of poor design

Comment: @spencer7593: thank u for your feedback, actually he is also having issue with mysqli_* OP not using $link identifier.

Comment: @devpro: so the call to mysqli_query function is failing, but the code isn't checking if it's successful or not. The code is putting its figurative pinky finger to the corner of its mouth with a Mike Myers Dr. Evil style "I just assume it will all go to plan. What?" Seems to me that' is the overarching error in the code. 
 Yes, the malformed mysqli_query function call is a problem. The bigger problem is ignoring (i.e. not detecting) the unsuccessful function call.

Comment: agreed , if query failed or not return anything then all calculation will be disturbed, because OP calculating directly ... @spencer7593 i hope these 2 comments will more to OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues in your code:

**Issue 1:** [`mysqli_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) required 2 parameters, you are not using your connection variable in your [`mysqli_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

**Issue 2:** if you want to sum like `$row['total'] + $row2['total'];` that then you must need to define alias in your query something like:

```
SELECT SUM(column) as total FROM tablename
```

Its better to use [PHP error reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on local environment, this will help you to check actual errors instead of blank pages.

**Example:**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**Edit:**

This is good point highlighted by @spencer7593 in comment, you are directly calculating both values, for suppose if your query not returns anything then you will get new error.

Comment: I add second parameters and i getting error

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/oy3a1d4rbftr/public_html/kbhproduction/admin/test.php on line 236

Comment: @JeetKumar: can u please explore this at once `https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php` param 1 should be connection and param 2 should be your query

Comment: glad to help u, also read comments which related to checks, you also need to add check either query executed or not, if query executed calculate otherwise show error.  @JeetKumar